# Method overriding from JAR file not working

Tags: java, overriding, jfreechart

I am trying to override `WaterfallBarRenderer` from JFreeChart library. I created a local class and extended the original `WaterfallBarRenderer` class, but I am not able to override the `drawItem()` method.

```
public class LocalWaterfall extends WaterfallBarRenderer {

    public LocalWaterfall() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void drawItem(Graphics2D g2, CategoryItemRendererState state, Rectangle2D dataArea, CategoryPlot plot,
        CategoryAxis domainAxis, ValueAxis rangeAxis, CategoryDataset dataset, int row, int column, int pass) {

        super.drawItem(g2, state, dataArea, plot, domainAxis, rangeAxis, dataset, row, column, pass);
        System.out.println("drwa item!!!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: So would you mind sharing the error message you get with us?

Comment: There is no error message. Its just that the overridden method is not getting called in the class that i defined. It is not overriding.

Comment: @Prabahar: Your `LocalWaterfall` works for me; if you still have problems, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: I found the the problem. There is an issue  in the parameter CategoryItemRendererState. Because the method drawItem which am overriding, calls a method in CategoryItemRendererState, setSeriesRunningTotal(), which is not visible here. The access modifier of setSeriesRunningTotal is default, so my class and method is not able to access it.